# how to fetch sqlite data based on columns

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I saved data on sqlite db with year and month, now want to retrieve data based on year and month but object is always null.
Here is my code

```
  public List<AddIncomeModel> fetch(String year,String month) {
    database = this.getReadableDatabase();
   // Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "  +YEAR +" = "+year+" AND " + MONTH + " = "+month,null);

    List<AddIncomeModel> contacts = new ArrayList<AddIncomeModel>();
    AddIncomeModel contactModel;
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
            cursor.moveToNext();
            contactModel = new AddIncomeModel();
            contactModel.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            contactModel.setIncome_source(cursor.getString(1));
            contactModel.setDescription(cursor.getString(2));
            contactModel.setAmount(cursor.getString(3));
            contacts.add(contactModel);
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    database.close();
    return contacts;
}
```

Please tell me where I am going wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Which object is null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQLiteDatabase.query() the selection comes in two parts. The where clause (a String) and the whereArgs (an array of String).

To add more than one condition to the where clause you can use AND or OR, just like && or || in Java.

A question mark in the where clause is bound to one of the Strings in the whereArgs array.

Try Like This

```
cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { ID, YEAR , MONTH},
YEAR + " LIKE ? AND " + MONTH+ " LIKE ?",                           
new String[] {"%" + dan + "%", "%" + vrijeme + "%"},
null, null, null, null);
```